# How to change the css of the div that i just created in code

Tags: jquery, css

I have the code just below, I don't even know if it works but I just wanted to learn how to change the css properties of the div that I just created within my JQuery structure. Like changing it's width, color and stuff.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#button").click(function () {
            jQuery("#button").html('Click me again');
            jQuery("#button").addClass("button1");
        });

        jQuery(".button1").click(function () {
            jQuery(".button1").hide();
            jQuery('<div />')
            .addClass('buttondiv')
            .css({
                'width': '150px',
                'height': '150px',
                'background-color': 'red'
            })
            .html(text)
            .appendTo("#maindiv");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to add styles to the element.

See the comments inline in the code:

```
jQuery('<div />') // Create new div element
    .addClass('buttondiv') // Add new class
    .css({ // Add inline styles
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'green'
    })
    .html(text)
    .appendTo("#maindiv"); // No need of `jQuery()` here
```

Comment: One more thing... The button that I've added a class does not work after the second click, any thoughts why?

Comment: @AltayMazlum You need to use `event delegation`

Comment: @AltayMazlum `$(document).on('click', '.buttondiv', function() { ... });` Use this

Comment: I did but this time, the button gets hidden even in the first click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82573/discussion-between-tushar-and-altay-mazlum).

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/css/

For a single property you can use:

```
$("#button").css("background-color","yellow");
```

For multiple style properties:

```
$("#button").css({"background-color":"yellow", "width":"50px"});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery css method in which you can set the css property as following

```
$(selector).css('width',100);

$(selector).css('color',red);
```

For more info read the css method of jQuery [click here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)